# Icon not shown on gnome(originally ubuntu mate) desktop

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-mate, desktop-icons

I installed downloaded ubuntu mate and installed gnome for better UI. Now no desktop icons are shown on it. And on
right-click only

1. Change background
2. Display settings
3. Settings

are shown. I want icons on my desktop. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reenable them:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

and starting nautilus (if it’s not already running).